# convert Double to array of digits

Tags: swift

Is there an easy way to convert

```
var amount : Double = 78.58
```

to: `var array = ["7", "8", "5", "8"]`

or `var array = [7, 8, 5, 8]`

and the other way around?

Comment: What is the purpose of the conversion? Are you aware that most decimal fractions are not represented exactly as a binary floating point number? Try `let amount = 0.3 - 0.2; print(amount)`.

Comment: All the data I have is in a format '12.34'. I have 4 pickers in which I want to display & edit that (01.23 or 1.23 is not possible). But thanks for your warning!

Comment: You mean you want an output array of 4 digits? from `[0,0,0,0]` to `[9,9,9,9]`?

Comment: yes, you're right.

Comment: It would be better to store the 4 digits as an *integer* (0-9999) and avoid all the rounding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let amount = 78.58
let res = "\(amount)".compactMap { $0 ==  "." ? nil : $0  } 
print(res)
```

For int

```
let res =  "\(amount)".compactMap { Int("\($0)") }
```

Comment: For `let amount = 0.3 - 0.2` you'll get the result `["0", "0", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "8"]`

Comment: @MartinR yes this would occur but op can give feedback if his double would be like this if so use `floor` / `ceil` / `round`

Comment: It also does not work with the scientific notation of floating point values, try `let amount = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude`

Comment: Why not simply `compactMap(Int.init)` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus `compactMap{Int($0)}`  has less characters

Comment: And what if the result should be [7, 8, 5, 8] ?

Comment: @LeoDabus your try gives sigmentation fault

Comment: @Sh_Khan: you mean: 'let b = "78.58".compactMap{Int($0)}' ? That gives an error 'Initializer 'init(_:radix:)' requires that 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') conform to 'StringProtocol''.

Comment: `let res =  "\(amount)".compactMap { Int("\($0)") }`

Comment: Got it. Works great!

Comment: Yes forgot that `Int` has no character initializer. Note that for **Swift 5 or later** you can use `Character` property `wholeNumberValue`. No need to convert from Character to String. `compactMap{$0.wholeNumberValue}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use the description method on Double to get a String object and work with that:

```
let amount = 78.58
let result = amount.description //result = "78.58"
```

Now you can iterate over the characters in the String:

```
for char in result {
    print("Found character: \(char)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to convert both from double and to double you need to keep the decimal separator

```
let elements = String(amount).map { String($0)}
let amount2 = elements.joined()
```

A more advanced solution for different precisions

```
func splitDouble(_ value: Double, precision: Double) -> [String] {
    let factor = pow(10, precision)
    let rounded = round(value * factor) / factor
    return String(rounded).map { String($0) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the 'joined' tip. In my use case the format is always '12.34' or '12,34' (depending languages). So no problem with keeping or loosing the decimal separator. I'll try to find the differences between your .map approach and the compactMap approach the others suggest.